# firebase permission-denied when I log out

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, flutter-getx

I am using Flutter GetX. I got `permission-denied` error. I don't know what I should do. I researched a lot this issue but I can't find anything. I am so new about flutter & firebase. I could not find what can I do? Please help me! I changed many times to firestore rules and did not change anything. I tried dispose but I got an issue

here my firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /subscribers/{subscriber} {
    
        allow get, write:if isSignIn() &&
        request.auth.token.phone_number == resource.data.phone;

            match /sites/{site} {
            allow read, write: if isSignIn();
          match /messages/{message}{
            allow read, write: if isSignIn();
          }
        }
    }
    match /sites/{site} {
        allow read, write: if isSignIn();
    }
  } 
  
  function isSignIn(){
    return request.auth.uid != null;
  }

}
```

here my homepage.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  String phoneNumber;
  HomePage({super.key, required this.phoneNumber});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  SitesControllers sitesControllers = Get.put(SitesControllers(), permanent: true);

  int actionController = 0;

  final fbServices = FirebaseServices();
  final _service = NotificationService();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _service.connectNotification();
    fbServices.saveToken(widget.phoneNumber);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
      Get.delete<SitesControllers>();
      super.dispose(); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<SitesControllers>(
        init: SitesControllers(),
        initState: (_) {},
        builder: (sitesControllers) {
          sitesControllers.getSites(widget.phoneNumber);
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: buildAppBarField("Home Page", false),
            // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
            body: sitesControllers.sitesList == null ? const Center(child: Text("no site"),) 
             : buildSiteField(context, widget.phoneNumber),
            floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            floatingActionButton: buildFloatActionButtonField(),
            bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBarField(),
          );
        },
      );
  }

  AppBar buildAppBarField(String title, bool back) {
    return AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: back,
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: ColorConstants.mainColor),
      elevation: 0.7,
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: ColorConstants.mainColor),
      ),
      actions: [
        PopupMenuButton(
          itemBuilder: (context) {
            return [
              PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [const Icon(Icons.unsubscribe), Text(" Unsubscribe", style: GoogleFonts.poppins(),)],
                  ))
            ];
          },
          onSelected: (value) {
            actionController = value;
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  } 

  Widget buildSiteField(BuildContext context, String number) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: context.dynamicHeight(0.02)),
      child: Obx(() => ListView.builder(
          itemCount: sitesControllers.sitesList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            fbServices.unreadCounter(number, sitesControllers.sitesList[index].id.toString());
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: context.dynamicWidth(0.05),
                  vertical: context.dynamicHeight(0.008)),
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: ColorConstants.mainColor, width: 2)),
                  child: ListTile(
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
                    dense: true,
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    onTap: () async {
                      await FirebaseAnalyticsServices.analytics.logEvent(
                        name: "visit_to_site", 
                        parameters: null
                      );
                      if(actionController == 1 ) {
                      } else {
                        buildListTileOnTapField(index, number);
                      }
                    },
                    leading: buildListTileLeadingField(
                        context,
                        sitesControllers.sitesList[index].name.toString(),
                        index),
                    subtitle: buildListTileSubstitleField(index),
                    trailing: buildListTileTrailingField(context, index, number),
                  )),
            );
          })),
    );
  }

  Widget buildListTileLeadingField(
      BuildContext context, String siteName, int index) {
    return Text(
              siteName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(),
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 27,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    );
  }

  Widget buildListTileSubstitleField(int index) {
    return Text(
      sitesControllers.sitesList[index].name.toString(),
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        fontSize: 15,
      )
    );
  }

  Widget buildListTileTrailingField(BuildContext context, int index, String number) {
    return actionController == 1 
     ? Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: context.dynamicHeight(0.005)),
        child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 20,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.unsubscribe),
          onPressed: () {
            Get.defaultDialog(
                textCancel: "CANCEL",
                textConfirm: "OK",
                middleText: "are you sure unsubscribe to this site?",
                onConfirm: () {
                  FirebaseServices().unsubscribeToSite(sitesControllers.sitesList[index].id.toString(), number);
                  Get.back();
                },
                onCancel: () {},
                buttonColor: ColorConstants.mainColor,
                cancelTextColor: ColorConstants.mainColor,
                confirmTextColor: Colors.white);
          },
          color: ColorConstants.deleteColor,
        ))
     : sitesControllers.sitesList[index].count == 0 ? 
     const Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right, color: ColorConstants.mainColor,) :
     Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: context.dynamicHeight(0.005)),
        child: Container(
          height: ScreenSize().height(context)*.05,
          width: ScreenSize().width(context)*.05,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle, 
            color: Colors.red),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(sitesControllers.sitesList[index].count.toString(), 
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white),),
          ))); 
          
  }

  Widget buildFloatActionButtonField() {
    return actionController == 1
        ? FloatingActionButton(
            
            onPressed: () {
              actionController = 0;
            },
            backgroundColor: ColorConstants.deleteColor,
            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          )
        : FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Get.to(() => SubscribeToSite(
                    phoneNumber: widget.phoneNumber,
                  ));
            },
            backgroundColor: ColorConstants.mainColor,
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          );
  }

  Widget buildBottomNavigationBarField() {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.borderColor, width: 1.5))),
      child: BottomAppBar(
        height: 55,
        notchMargin: 0.0,
        elevation: 8,
        shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  
                  Get.to(() => ProfilePage(phoneNumber: widget.phoneNumber,));
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.person_3),
                color: ColorConstants.borderColor),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if(mounted) {
                  // çıkış yaparken bi hata alıyoruz
                  try { 
                    dispose();
                    PhoneAuthController().quitFirebaseAuth();
                  } catch (e) {
                    return;
                  }
                  }
                
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
              color: ColorConstants.borderColor,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // FUNCTIONS
  void buildListTileOnTapField(int index, String number) {
    String siteKey = sitesControllers.sitesList[index].id.toString();
    
    fbServices.readAllMessages(widget.phoneNumber, siteKey);
    Get.to(() => MessagesPage(
          number: number,
          siteKey: sitesControllers.sitesList[index].id.toString(),
          siteName: sitesControllers.sitesList[index].name.toString(),
        ));
  }
}
```

What issue I got when I used `disposed();`

here issue image

[image]

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

permission-denied error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spJP7.png

Comment: The exception you get does not seem to ahve anything to do with Firestore rules, or am I missing something?

Comment: @l1b3rty I aggree with you about not any error in Firestore Rules. I think " GetxControllers still is trying getting data from Firestore when I sign out." but I disposed my Controllers from memory then I sign out but It still is giving permission-denied error.

Comment: How do you know it is giving a permission-denied error? Can you show the logs?

Comment: I added a image in question.